# Call dynamic named function array key and insert its value to parameter

Tags: php

I want to call asso1(), asso2(), asso3() function from my $key array value and also want to input the parameter for each `$key` which is 1,2,3 now as set. So on current status i am getting output `111` but it should be `123`. How can i achieve that?

```
function asso1($a) {
  // echo "output form asso1<br>";
  return $a;
}
function asso2($b) {
  // echo "output form asso2<br>";
  return $b;
}
function asso3($c) {
  // echo "output form asso3";
  return $c;
}


$asso = array("asso1"=>"1", "asso2"=>"2", "asso3"=>"3");

foreach ($asso as $key => $_asso) {

    $ar[] = $_asso;
    $fv = call_user_func_array($key,$ar);

  print_r($fv);

}
```

Comment: Try just `call_user_func_array($key,array($_asso));`

Comment: What you are doing with this `$ar[] = $_asso;` is sending `array('1')` then `array(1,2)`, then `array(1,2,3)` and you are only sending back the first parameter which is `1`

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have better luck if you do:

```
foreach($asso as $key => $_asso) {
    $fv = call_user_func_array($key,array($_asso));
    print_r($fv);
}
```

When you do array push like you have you are just building an array but only every returning the first parameter which is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this codes bellow. it should work as you wants.

```
$asso = array("asso1"=>"1", "asso2"=>"2", "asso3"=>"3");

foreach ($asso as $key => $_asso) {

    // $ar[] = $_asso;
    // $fv = call_user_func_array($key,$ar);

    $fv = call_user_func_array($key,array($_asso));

  print_r($fv);

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference between what I did and what you did 2 minutes later as well as the comment 15 mins before that??

Comment: ah sorry dear. i just checked that you have put the comments not answer so i tested the code and tried to put a answer. sorry my dear friend if i did something wrong.